# What is the most appropriate Natspec tag to use for struct properties?

Tags: solidity, struct

For each struct property, what is the most appropriate Natspec tag to describe what it is? Is it acceptable to use `@param`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to leave a comment. As much as conventions are determined by developers actually doing things in practice, I have been [using @param for struct properties](https://github.com/SuperFarmDAO/SuperFarm-Contracts/blob/e33a0a5e62d4b07622c0972090a0f75f20c528a8/contracts/staker/v1/Staker.sol#L78) in production for several years now. I also use it for documenting events.